# uniform integrability characterization

Tags: probability, probability-theory, lp-spaces, uniform-integrability

How to show the following:

When a family of random variables $ \{X_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ is $L^p$ bounded for some 
$p > 1$ then $ \{X_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ is uniformly integrable.

Also why does the above statement fail for $p \leq 1$? Could you give counterexamples?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the definition of uniform integrability that you were given? There are usually two parts in it, which part are you unable to show? (That you flout the rules of the site so squarely after 78 questions asked is worrisome.)

Comment: I am not flouting any rule of the site.  I dont understand why you keep commenting on my questions with no help.  I dont want and need your comments. Please stop commenting on my problems. I am tired of reporting you for your unnecessary comments.

Comment: Your beliefs about the ways the site works are unfounded. (1) That a user comments on your questions, and what they comment, is not for you to decide. (2) That you are flouting the rules of the site is a fact (and what is so difficult about adding your thoughts on the questions you asked if you tried, even minimally, to solve them? even more troublesome, why do you fail to even ackowledge the queries for explanations made in comments?). (3) To signal this behaviour to other users, especially to newcomers, is useful unless they think the site is supposed to function the way you are using it.

Comment: If you click on the flag next to comments you see that the question owner has the right to comment on what the others comment on his/her question. You better check the rules of this site more carefully. Moreover, you are not the one who decides what and how to post on this site. I am sorry that I am in this debate with you. All people who are posting questions are trying to do math and learn math unless some "quick homework answers" are asked which are obvious from the questions anyway.

Comment: Of course the question owner has the right to comment on what the others comment on their questions, did I ever write otherwise? (Feels like having to explain that $P\implies Q$ is not the same as $Q\implies P$...) // *All people who are posting questions are trying to do math*... Precisely, you are not. Copying on the site 78 verbatim questions you were asked to solve and waiting for the answers to appear without interacting with the answerers (even to correct [obvious misprints when asked about them](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/366201)) is not, I repeat, is not, "doing maths".

Comment: "Copying on the site 78 verbatim questions you were asked to solve" this is outrageously wrong in its most polite way! Thank you for pointing out that  "obvious misprints when asked about them" question. Could you please find also to which homework it belongs?? I misread that index in the equality when I was reading something :) and it turned something completely difficult when i was reading it!! So you assumed that was homework and you declare here that way as i said "outrageously wrong" in its polite way! I report you again!

Comment: What prevented you "to correct obvious misprints when asked about them" before? What prevents you now to add "your thoughts on the questions you asked if you tried, even minimally, to solve them"? On this question, what prevents you to provide, when explicitly asked for, "the definition of uniform integrability that you were given"? Inverting these three questions, one gets three concrete guidelines to make your future questions on the site more acceptable. Your choice is to adopt them, or to further alienate some potential answerers.

Comment: You did not, somebody else did it for you. // OK, enough (but if ever you find the time, for your own good, try to ponder my last comment).

Comment: Have a nice day. No hard feelings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** whatever definition of uniform integrability you use, you can tackle the problem using Hölder's inequality. [De la Vallée-Poussin's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability) theorem gives a partial converse.

A counter-example could be $X_n:=n\chi_{(0,n^{-1})}$.